# How to show which students are still in school using sql

Tags: sql

This table shows the records of students entering and leaving the school. IN represents student entering school and OUT represents student leaving school. I wondering how to show which students are still in school.

I'm trying so much but still cannot figure it out, does anyone can help me, Thank you so much.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`;
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `time` varchar(128) default NULL,
  `status` varchar(128) default NULL,
  `stu_id` varchar(128) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) 

INSERT INTO `student` (`id`, `time`, `status`, `stu_id`) VALUES 
    (1,'11AM','IN','1'),
    (2,'11AM','IN','2'),
    (3,'12AM','OUT','1'),
    (4,'12AM','IN','3'),
    (5,'1PM','OUT','3'),
    (6,'2PM','IN','3'),
    (11,'2PM','IN','4');
```

I expect the answer is 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 2):

The number of students in the school is the sum of the ins minus the sum of the outs:

```
select sum(case when status = 'in' then 1
                when status = 'out' then -1
                else 0
           end)
from student;
```

Basically to see the students who are in the school, you want the students whose last status is `in`.  One way uses a correlated subquery:

```
select s.stu_id
from student s
where s.time = (select max(s2.time)
                from student s2
                where s2.stu_id = s.stu_id
               ) and
      s.status = 'in';
```

Comment: but if i need show the stu_id which is still in the school, how do I do

Answer (score 0):

If `status` is either only `IN` or `OUT` can't you do 
`SELECT * from student WHERE status="IN"`

Answer (score 0):

here's the query considering the auto increment id

```
select t2.* from  
student t2 
left join (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by stu_id ORDER BY id desc) as row_num, id from student) t1 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.row_num = 1 and [status] = 'IN'
```